# cleaning up JSON data

Tags: php, json, decode, encode

ok for some reason when I print_r my json I get the following

```
[{"value":{"givenName":"stream","middleName":null,"familyName":"101","prefix":null,"suffix":null,"givenNameSound":null,"familyNameSound":null}}]
```

however value should = an email address and then it has the other fields givenName etc.

What I want to do is only print out the ones that have value field in ie myemail@myemail.com

how would I do this with PHP.

How I am currently doing it

```
$contacts = $queryResponse->query->results->contact;
          //print_r($contacts);
          foreach($contacts as $contact) {
            $contact = json_encode($contact);
            $contact = json_decode($contact);
            if($contact->fields->value != NULL)
            {
            print "[".json_encode($contact->fields)."]";
            //print_r($contact->fields->value);
            }
```

Comment: what is the point of encoding and then immediately decoding `$contact`?

Comment: Also, it's really unclear what your question is.

Comment: i think he's mimicking an input

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/json_last_error) to find out. (Upgrade to PHP 5.3 for testing.)

Whenever you receive `NULL` values in the encoded JSON string, the input character set wasn't valid UTF-8. That's one of the requirements listed in the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) manual page.